# Export MySQL table to CSV with custom header

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

Why when i try to export MySql table to CSV with `header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');` It doesn't get done properly:

- it does create the CSV file
- however it does it on the beginning of the file, where the page code is
- and after the code the is table content

This is the code witch exports it:

```
$this->view->table = $model->info('name');

$is_csv = $this->_getParam('csv');

if ($this->_request->isPost() && $is_csv) {
    $fichier = 'file.csv';

    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fichier.'"');

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
    $data = $model->fetchAll();

    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields->toArray());
    }

     fclose($fp);
}
```

And here i'm calling this with button:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?php echo $this->table ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="csv" value="csv">
        <?php echo Core_Locale::translate('CSV')?>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are still getting this wrapped in your layout. You should be doing all this directly from the controller disabling both the layout and view. Are you using ZF2 or ZF1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code up in your application then application create view.
I had same issue but i solved it this way..

- i put peace of code to function/block and place it over echo or render html
- put exit; on the end of function/block

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $csv = new Csv();
        $filename = $csv->generateFileDate();

        if($filename !== false) {
            $data = file_get_contents($csv->folder .'reports/'. $filename);
            header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="'.$filename.'";');
            echo $data;
            exit;
        }
    }

    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="us">
    <head> .........
```

hope this help to you

Comment: Thank you! The if in if and exit really did the work :)